# How do I determine the current blocksize of an APFS filesystem and is it possible to change?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, filesystems, virtualization, apfs

Documentation for APFS is sparse and unhelpful. I'm on a MacBook Pro and trying to make IO requests more efficient in VMs, currently qemu disk image is using a block size of 16k, and the xfs filesystem on the VM is also using a blocksize of 16k, the disk itself appears to have a block size of 8k, but I don't know what the blocksize of APFS is or how to find it out. I don't even know if APFS has a concept of blocksize. Essentially I'm trying to see if I can set APFS to bundle it's disk transactions at the same size as the IO transactions in qemu and the guest linux VM so that I can improve the somewhat abysmal performance I'm getting.

For reference, I'm a linux sysadmin and my knowledge of Mac is very limited.

Comment: I found this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42509/how-to-get-hfs-filesystem-blocksize which suggests using `stat -f "%k" FILE` to find the "optimal I/O operation block size" I don't know if this is an authoritative way to tell the block size of APFS or not.

Comment: This might be relevant - https://eclecticlight.co/2022/07/05/why-are-disk-images-so-slow-at-writing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do it the 'dumb' way? Make a tiny text file & Get Info?

Same file -  left HFS, right APFS

[image]

For the tough bit, changing the bock size, I haven't a clue, sorry. As a Mac user of some 30+ years I've never had to pick a block size in my life ;)

Comment: Well, this is close enough. Thank you. Maybe I'll set the whole stack to 4k blocks/clusters and see if that improves performance.