# FAT32 partition unusual storage usage on MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, partitioning, filesystems, fat32

I have Linux installed on a second partition on my MacBook Air M1 running MacOS Ventura. To share data between the two systems, I shrunk the system partition in MacOS, then booted into Linux and created a partition that uses all the free unallocated space (about 32GB), formatted as fat32.

I booted back into MacOS and copied over some code files to the new partition. The problem is, the code files I copied over take up less than 12GB on the system partition, but on the fat32 partition they use up about 28GB.

What could be the cause of this? I notice that the . and .. folders on the fat32 partition are about 32kb each in size in each folder, whereas they are usually like 100 bytes on the system partition.

Comment: It will depend on your block size when you formatted. I have no idea how to 'properly' find the block size [never needed to] but see https://superuser.com/a/1787970/347380 for a related issue & simple way to determine it.

Comment: small file size vs. big cluster size = wasted space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably 32KB clusters which means to store a 100 byte file, you waste (32768 bytes - 100 bytes).

A single cluster is smallest size that can be allocated to a single file. If file is smaller than size of a single cluster, the rest of the cluster is considered 'slack' but does take up space.

Example, 8 sector / cluster cluster size:

[image]

File slightly overshooting single cluster:

[image]

Resulting in two clusters being allocated to the file, creating 3649 bytes slack.

The file system is irrelevant, in this case NTFS, same goes for FAT32, exFAT.